# How to hide -> move ->show -> an element in loop?

Tags: jquery

```
$parent.animate({'left': '-='+parentLeft+'px'}, options.speed, options.easing, function(){
if(slideLoop){
$parent.css('left', '-'+getSlidePosition(currentSlide, 'left')+'px');
}
```

I need to animate $parent in sequence: hide -> move ->show ->
and I need to adapt to the above code.

Already it only moves...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the

```
$('#parent').hide()
```

and

```
$('#parent').show()
```

methods before and after your move code

Comment: Thank you - I have used: $parent.animate({opacity: 0});